# Capture video stream flask

Tags: python, swift, flask, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I have created a simple live video stream from the raspberry camera. It looks like this

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import Response

import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

def gen():
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, img = camera.read()

        if ret:
            frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        else:
            break

app.run(host='192.168.0.241', port=7070, debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PiCamera stream</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Streaming</h1>
        <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything works correct, I enter `http://<raspberry_ip>:<port>` in the browser and I can see the video.

Right now I need to create mobile app for watching this video, however I am struggling how to do it. Is there a way to capture video stream in iOS app?

Comment: What does this have to do with flask? You've used a web framework to make a video stream, but that is unrelated to an iOS app. How can this be reasonably answered without building the entire app?

Comment: Well, I am just discovering video streaming topic, first found flask and thought it looks good. I don't have to use flask, can be any other library or framework. Maybe you recommend something?

Comment: You could potentially use kivy but I've barely used it. Flask is a web framework, though. You can access your stream in the browser but, unless I'm missing something, it's unrelated to the app you want to make

Comment: Thanks for info @roganjosh, will check it. I believe that there are plenty of libs in python for streaming, however the biggest challenge for me is to get stream in iOS app.

Comment: Heiii. I also have same problem. I need to display stream from PI camera to my app.

Comment: First of all, if you were to do this, you would need to stream the video to be outside just your own network. You would need a domain to stream on to. Once you have that setup, use WebViews to iframe the url.

Answer (score 0):

Your video is streaming on

```
http://<raspberry_ip>:<port>/video_feed
```

Answer (score 0):

`http://<raspberry_ip>:<port>`

Using Ngrok if you want to push your app to public server!
http://ngrok.com/